# Under Windows7, why it prompts TomCat?

Tags: tomcat

Under Windows 7, it prompts to say "failed to start the Tomcat service" when I restart the computer. However Tomcat is started up. Any reason?

Comment: My guess is admin privileges, If you are admin you probably have UAC on? try disabling UAC and going on an admin account and see if the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably have tomcat starting in two separate places.  Check msconfig and go to the start up tab.  Look to see if you have tomcat starting as a service and in the registry / startup folder.